# Moving Finished React Native App On Windows to Mac for Generate IPA

Tags: windows, macos, react-native

I am trying to create a React Native application for both android and ios. I have a PC with Windows 10 in it. I know that I can only develop android applications because in Windows, there is no SDK's what xcode has.

I wonder that if I could just finish an application in windows and copy the whole project folder then transport it to a MAC after finishing the app. I thought with this way, I could generate an output which is available to upload on AppStore.

Ps. I am aware of the existence of Expo but due to some reasons I wanted to solve this question.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to, however it is not a good idea to build a react-native app on one platform and then hope that it works as expected on the other. It is much better to build while checking that they work on each platform.

Comment: Okay first, thanks for your response. I am a real newbie on React Native so I want to ask that, in React N. are we going to code for both ios and android separately in some part? Because I saw two folders on videos which are "ios" and "android" in the project.

Comment: you can also upload your project to github (to a private repository), and syncronize it with git

Comment: You'll write most of your code in javascript and won't touch the native code unless you need to link packages or write your own native modules. If you don't want to handle native code then you should avoid `react-native init` and go with `Expo`. Though `Expo` has limitations due to the fact that the native code is abstracted away. If you cannot develop full time on a mac then you should probably develop using `Expo`. Otherwise, you will have completed an awesome app on Android, but the iOS version won't work for some reason and it may be difficult to figure out why.

Comment: I appreciate for suggestion @ValdaXD. 

Okay I guess I will try to find a friend who is capable of programming with MAC. Then begin as purely native. Thank you again for your concern. Have a good programming everyone.

Comment: Yeah i use it not to share code but to build for ios , since appcenter supports cloud builds using github repos i don't need a mac to build for ios, and to develop i use windows w/ android, and if i conditionally render for IOS i use codepush to not build again the app for ios 7u7